# UIWebview gets stuck with the following message in console

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

UIWebview gets stuck with the following message in console.

```
void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*): delegate (webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:)   
failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
```

anyone knows what this is??

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Are you using any Javascript on the page you are loading?

Specifically, are you using the method

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script
```

As the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) state the following

> JavaScript execution time is limited to 10 seconds for each top-level entry point. If your script executes for more than 10 seconds, the web view stops executing the script

And this seems to tie in with the error message you are seeing in the console

Comment: im working on a twitter app. The webview loads the twitter login page. After i have entered my credentials and clicked "Authorize app" my modal view controller dismisses but the buttons on the background view is stuck

Comment: Can you post any of your code so I can get a better idea of how you've implemented things?

For instance, do you manually enable/disable the buttons on the background view, and if so are you using the webView's delegate methods to manage this?

Comment: I have solved the problem. There was a background view that wasn't removing after i dismiss the modal view controller. Anyway thanks micpringle for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, it looks like my particular timeout was occurring due to a javascript error in rare scenarios. You might try wrapping your JS in a try/catch or improving it to be more error-tolerant.

---

More details: I was using the following JS string:

```
NSString* js = @"document.getElementById(\"main\").offsetHeight";
int height = [[_web_view stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js] intValue];
```

I knew that this UIWebView problem could happen if the web view was not fully loaded (eg. JS called before the webViewDidFinishLoad: method, so I guessed that perhaps the "main" object was missing. Thus, I modified my JS to the following and it worked:

```
NSString* js = @"document.getElementById(\"main\") ? document.getElementById(\"main\").offsetHeight : -1";
```

Comment: Hmmm this sounds interesting, can anyone else cofirm that this helps solving the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Below code snippet worked for me.

```
if(!webview.isLoading)
{
   // update your code.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use WKWebView instead of UIWebView.this works for me.

In my case, I try to use UIWebView to open local PDF.some of the PDF may contain some JS code.then I run into this problem.

After using WKWebView, everything works just perfect

Apple also recommends you to use WKWebView if your app that runs in iOS 8 and later