# How can we find webview loaded with the content in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, xcode, object, uiwebview

i am using this method as follows.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoading:(UIWebView *)webView
```

This method to know whether the webview is finished loading or not but once this method is 
  called i am not getting the web content on my view, it is taking some time to show.

My problem is i want to know when the webview is fully loaded with the content.

Can any one please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

paas web view delegates and use these function -

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

Comment: Yes i am using the same method "- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView" but to see the content it is taking some time....but want to know how to find that the view is loade with web content

Comment: - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
 this method will tell you that the content that you are trying to load is loaded

Comment: i am getting these below errors. can any one tell me what is the meaning of these: void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForMIMEType:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

Comment: i think the page you are trying to load having some heavy content so that it failed after 10 seconds callback time. so you can check out this question may be this one helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489601/uiwebview-gets-stuck-with-the-following-message-in-console